# how to get ID from ActionLink in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Well I have just stated working on MVC so i dont know i to get ID and Name from action link I have Action link and it has Name and ID i want when i will redirect it on next page i need these ID and Name there ...thanx in advance

```
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CmpName)
            </th>
            <th>
                Select Company
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CmpName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Select Company", "UserDashBoard", "User", new { 
                    item.CmpName,item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is code which you want

**View Side Code:-**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select Company", "UserDashBoard", "User", new { 
                id=item.ID,name=item.CmpName, })
```

**Controller Side Code:-**

```
    public ActionResult UserDashBoard (int? id, string name)
    {
```

Comment: before asking my question i have used it but i was not working

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UserDashBoard(Int32, System.String)' in '_11ITAccountPro.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: it means you have item.id is nullable value right ?

Comment: If name is also nullable then pass parameter name as nullable like id.

Answer (score 1):

Just took this straight out of project:
// I have a list of documents in a table:

```
foreach( var item in Model.DocumentList)
{

    <td>
    @Html.ActionLink( "Delete","Delete", "Document",new{ id= item.Id, tenancyId = item.TenancyId}, null );
    <td>
}
```

In this case the ID should never be null as we got it from an item in a list of documents so it wont need to be Nullable

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, int tenancyId)
{
    var model = new DeleteViewModel();
    model.PageTitle = "example";
    model.PageHeader = "example";

    var documents = _db.Document.Single(a=>a.Id == id);

    _db.Document.Remove(documents);

    return View(model)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional note on the link, remember to add the null.

You'll get "Length=" at the end of the URL instead of the ID like you'd expect without it.